# Arduino IDE boards master list

Tags: discussion

I'm compiling a "master list" of board packages for the Arduino IDE.

At the moment I have:

- Adafruit

  - https://adafruit.github.io/arduino-board-index/package_adafruit_index.json
- BBC Microbit etc

  - https://sandeepmistry.github.io/arduino-nRF5/package_nRF5_boards_index.json
- chipKIT

  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chipKIT32/chipKIT-core/master/package_chipkit_index.json
- Digistump

  - http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json
- ESP32

  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json
- ESP8266

  - https://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
- Little Green LGT8fx

  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dbuezas/lgt8fx/master/package_lgt8fx_index.json
- Maixduino

  - http://dl.sipeed.com/MAIX/Maixduino/package_Maixduino_k210_index.json
- Open Panzer TCB

  - https://openpanzerproject.github.io/OpenPanzerBoards/package_openpanzer_index.json
- Seeeduino

  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_Platform/master/package_seeeduino_boards_index.json
- Sparkfun Boards

  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkfun/Arduino_Boards/master/IDE_Board_Manager/package_sparkfun_index.json
- STM32Duino

  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stm32duino/BoardManagerFiles/master/STM32/package_stm_index.json

If anyone knows of any more (the more obscure the better, even if it's just for one single board) please let me know in answers / comments.

Comment: https://github.com/per1234/ino-hardware-package-list

Comment: @Juraj Oooh, nice find. Thanks for that one.

Comment: Of course it will take some work going through all those looking for the links to the board installation JSON file where available. Many are grouped into a single file, like the Adafruit ones...

Comment: I did know about this list. Per is very active in Arduino community mainly on Arduino forum and recently he even started to work for Arduino. He writes documentation (CLI afalk). But he avoids Arduino SE for some reason.

Comment: Well, it's a great resource. Basically I'm looking to (eventually) migrate UECIDE to using (at least sometimes) `arduino-cli` as the compilation back-end, and want to have a way of selecting the boards / cores without you having to go hunting for them.

Comment: the CLI has boards manager services too. and it can run as RPC server (daemon)

Comment: Yes. But you still need to know the JSON file URLs. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: the json links, right. there is no index of then anywhere. they are always mentioned in readme only

Comment: @Juraj Yeah. That file you link to has many of them, but not all. And some are b0rken too.

Comment: Is this one? For Sanguino: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lauszus/Sanguino/master/package_lauszus_sanguino_index.json. I think that's for a 3D Printing board, I think, can't remember, I may have some others.